# Dojo.Connect Event doesn't get called - why?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, dojo

I am trying to connect an `onMouseDown` event to an image with `dojo.connect` like:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("workpic"), "onMouseDown", workpicDown);

function workpicDown()
{
    alert("mousedown");
}
```

Similar code a few lines later, where I'm connecting `onMouse*` events to `dojo.body` does work completely properly.

but when I click on the image, I'm not seeing the alert window, so the event doesn't get called. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"onMouseDown" should be all lower case when used with DOM events as opposed to Widget events. Try:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("workpic"), "onmousedown", workpicDown);
```

From the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/events.html#quickstart-events):

> A note about the event names: Event
>   names now are lower case, except in
>   special cases (e.g., some Mozilla DOM
>   events). Dojo will add "on" to your
>   event name if you leave it off (e.g.,
>   'click' and 'onclick' are the same
>   thing to dojo). This differs from
>   Widget Events in the sense Dijit uses
>   mixedCase event names, to avoid
>   potential conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's problem with execution context. Try to use fallowing:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("workpic"), "onMouseDown",window, "workpicDown");

window.workpicDown = function()
{
    alert("mousedown");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sadly it doesn't work either. With error: `uncaught exception: dojo.hitch: scope["workpicDown"] is null (scope="[object Window]")`

Comment: hmm.. This means that the event is triggered.. Could you provide a bit more code?

Comment: That error occurs when loading the page, not when clicking the image. When I'm clicking the image, nothing happens.

Comment: Okay thank you, moving the connect under the functions and lowercasing the event names (onMouseDown -> onmousedown) -basically- works. But now it seems to capture the mouse events anywhere than only on the image.

Comment: I don't fully understand that. Are you saying that i should connect the event to the `dojo.byId("workpic")` scope, instead of the `window` scope?

Comment: dojo.connect(obj, event, context, method): obj - The source object for the event function (DOM Node in your case); event - name of the event function in obj ("onmousedown"); context - The object that method will receive as "this" (e.g. "window" object); method - A function reference, or name of a function in context (e.g. "window.alertClick"); E.g. add event listener to some div and image : dojo.connect(dojo.byId('div1'), "onmousedown", window, window.AlertOnDivClick); dojo.connect(dojo.byId('img1'), "onmousedown", window, window.AlertOnImageClick);