# Add onchange event to javascript widget after creation

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following snippet:

```
    var divCombo = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
        id: "clientDivision",
        name: "clientDivision.name",
        value:"${project?.clientDivision?.encodeAsHTML()}",
        required: "true",
        store: divStore,
        pageSize:"15"
    },divisionNode);

    divCombo.onchange = function(){
            setCbHiddenId(this, 'clientDivision.id');
    };
```

This doesnt seem to be firing the setCbHiddenId function. I change values in the divCombo combo box, and firebug never stops at my breakpoint set int he script.

What am I doing wrong exactly? I tried to define it after the fact since it needs a reference to itself in the onchange function.

Comment: divCombo is a "dojo widget (or dijit) object", not a DOM object.  It does **not** have "onchange".  Instead it is "onChange" (notice the capitalization) property.  In general, mixed cases for widget events and all lowercase for DOM events.  To get the DOM object, you can use divCombo.domNode.  However, the best practice is to use `dojo.connect` to hook up your events.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs you could either connect the widget to a function or you can watch the widget's value (needs 1.6+).

The connect method. You'll need make sure that 'this' is the correct object. It's divCombo in this example. Also, dijits use capitalized events (onChange instead of onchange)

```
divCombo.connect(divCombo, 'onChange', function(newValue) {
    setCbHiddenId(this, 'clientDivision.id');
});
```

The watch method. Again, be careful with 'this' inside functions.

```
divCombo.watch('value', function(property, oldValue, newValue) {
    setCbHiddenId(this, 'clientDivision.id');
})
```

Comment: @missingno lol, yep. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431381/dojo-connect-event-doesnt-get-called-why/5432451#5432451

Comment: Im sorry, that should have been a comment